# Nested TabNavigator not passing params to routes

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a TabNavigator nested in an Stack Navigator. In a login page, I want to navigate to the TabNavigator, resetting the stack and passing some params to the TabNavigator.

As described in the docs, I'm doing the followin to reset the stack, passing the `user` param to the navigator.

```js
  resetAction = () => {
    return NavigationActions.reset({
      index:0,
      actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({routeName:'TabNav', params:{user: userId}})]
    })
  }
```

My problem is that i can't access the params in the TabNavigator routes. I tried using `this.props.navigation.state.params` or `this.props.navigation.params` but none seem to work.

My tabNavigator code:

```js
const TabNav = TabNavigator({
    Page1:{screen: Page1},
    Page2: {screen: Page2},
    Page3: {screen: Page3}
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by changing the TabNav component to a class based component as seen below:

```js
export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  
  router = const TabNav = TabNavigator({
    Page1:{screen: Page1},
    Page2: {screen: Page2},
    Page3: {screen: Page3}
  })

  render(){
    return <TabNav screenProps={{userId: this.props.navigation.state.params.userId}}/>
  }
}
```

Doing that I'm able to normally pass params such as `NavigationActions.navigate({routeName:'TabNav', params:{userId}}` and access to the userId param in the routes in the screenProps property as in `this.props.screenProps.userId`

Comment: whats that router variable?